# Packer provisioners failing on azure-arm

Tags: azure-resource-manager, packer

I have the following build in a Packer .hcl file.  The first provisioner succeeds but the other two always fail.  Does anyone have a working azure-arm provisioner to install software on a Windows image?

```
build {
    sources = ["source.azure-arm.autogenerated_1"]

    provisioner "powershell" {
        inline = ["Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server", "while ((Get-Service RdAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }", "while ((Get-Service WindowsAzureGuestAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }", "& $env:SystemRoot\\System32\\Sysprep\\Sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /quiet /quit", "while($true) { $imageState = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Setup\\State | Select ImageState; if($imageState.ImageState -ne 'IMAGE_STATE_GENERALIZE_RESEAL_TO_OOBE') { Write-Output $imageState.ImageState; Start-Sleep -s 10  } else { break } }"]
    }
    provisioner "powershell" {
        #  inline = ["Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force", "Invoke-Expression((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"]
        #  inline = ["Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"]
        inline = ["Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"]
    }

    provisioner "powershell" {
        inline = ["choco install -y 7zip", "choco install -y notepadplusplus"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the order. The following part of your provisioner is responsible for the generalization process, which should be run last

```
"while ((Get-Service WindowsAzureGuestAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }", "& $env:SystemRoot\\System32\\Sysprep\\Sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /quiet /quit", "while($true) { $imageState = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Setup\\State | Select ImageState; if($imageState.ImageState -ne 'IMAGE_STATE_GENERALIZE_RESEAL_TO_OOBE') { Write-Output $imageState.ImageState; Start-Sleep -s 10  } else { break } }"
```

Change the order of provisioners or add your commands above the generalization phase

```
build {
    sources = ["source.azure-arm.autogenerated_1"]

    provisioner "powershell" {
        inline = ["Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"]
    }
    
    provisioner "powershell" {
        inline = ["choco install -y 7zip", "choco install -y notepadplusplus"]
    }

    provisioner "powershell" {
        inline = [
            "Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server",
            "ADD YOUR COMMANDS HERE"
            "while ((Get-Service RdAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }",
            "while ((Get-Service WindowsAzureGuestAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }",
            "& $env:SystemRoot\\System32\\Sysprep\\Sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /quiet /quit",
            "while($true) { $imageState = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Setup\\State | Select ImageState; if($imageState.ImageState -ne 'IMAGE_STATE_GENERALIZE_RESEAL_TO_OOBE') { Write-Output $imageState.ImageState; Start-Sleep -s 10  } else { break } }"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This works on Windows 2019 datacenter.  I create an image and a vm from that image and I can login via rdp and see the installed software.  If I try Windows 10 win10-21h2-ent it creates an image and I can create a VM, but logging in with RDP hangs (wait cursor).  The Activity Log doesn't show any problem.

Are there any good docs on how to use provisioner?  The Hashicorp docs only include useless examples like echo'ing strings.

Comment: That should be Windows 2016 datacenter.

Comment: For me it looks like problem with Windows itself. I didnt try to use Packer with Windows 10. The most important thing is to [generalize OS (sysprep)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/generalize) in the last step. It should be almost the same for all Windows servers. There is an example how to do it with Windows 2016 [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/build-image-with-packer).